# Advices fail on Emacs Snapshot

Tags: emacs, elisp

Recent (days) changes in Emacs bzr has triggered a really strange error in code using `defadvice` that worked with previous versions of Emacs. Typically I get for example

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument symbolp #[(file newname &optional ok-if-already-exists)
...
ad-activate(rename-file nil)
```

when trying to load a compiled version of for example

```
(defadvice rename-file (around sync-ectags-rename-file (file newname &optional ok-if-already-exists) activate)
    "Update ectags for renaming of FILE to NEWNAME."
    (ectags-unregister-tag-file file)
    ad-do-it
    (ectags-register-tag-file newname))
```

However evaluating the expression using `C-x C-e` above works fine. I've tried for hours to figure out what is wrong but with no luck. Similar problems occur in several other cases where I advice functions.

Comment: Why would you use StackOverflow to raise a bug report about a snapshot built from source control? `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: I of course agree completely with phils, and will add that I encourage people to use the `emacs-24` branch nowadays, so as to help us fix bugs before the 24.3 release.

Comment: The bug has been fixed in more recent versions. I will not use stackoverflow any more for these things. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

This was an upstream bug. Have a look at the discussion [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2012-11/msg00177.html). As far as I know there are a lot of internal changes going on right now as Emacs 24.3 will be switching from around advices to wrapper-hooks.

Comment: Aha! Interesting. What is an around-hook?

Comment: Take a look at their documentation. <kbd>C-h v</kbd> `with-wrapper-hooks`. Basically it's a more robust replacement for around advices.

Comment: @BozhidarBatsov: while the new advice mechanism is reminiscent of `with-wrapper-hook` (when used with `:around`), this is not a move from "around advice" to "with-wrapper-hook".  It's just a new lightweight advice library, which also happens to make `with-wrapper-hook` obsolete.